# Where does Xcode store archived frameworks?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I created an Xcode project with the "Cocoa Framework" template. When I archive it, it isn't visible in the Organizer.

Where are the archives stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting custom locations or messing with Xcode's preferences, you could just include a **`Copy Files Build Phase`** that should add the archived Framework properly into Organizer.

[image]

Using an `Absolute Path` with the variable`$(BUILD_DIR)`seems to work fine. You should then find any archives in XCode's Organizer or in:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives

Answer (score 4):

From Apple ( to view or change archive location ):

- Choose Xcode > Preferences, and click Locations.
- Choose Custom from the Archives pop-up menu.
- Click the folder icon in the text field, and choose a location.

When you go on Xcode Preference :

> Archive location : /Users/YourName/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives

Comment: Is that setting global for every project? If it is then you might add that to your answer... anyway, +1 for emphasis on documentation even though it might not be the best solution.