# Xcode 10.1: How do I export my Archive from this location?

Tags: xcode

I just successfully built an **Archive** of a project in Xcode 10.1.

I went into **Window** -> **Organizer** and I see no archived application:

[image]

I have been following this documentation:
https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Creating+an+ipa+File#CreatinganipaFile-Buildingan.ipaFile

and this one:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A+Create+an+.ipa+file+from+XCode

I also followed this Stack Overflow question:
[Where does Xcode store archived frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104921/where-does-xcode-store-archived-frameworks)

but again no archive:

[image]

If the **Archive** is being selected and it says successfully built, where is my **Archive**?

With help from Rudedog, I saw that my archive is here `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<date>/ProjectName <date>.xcarchive`, but how do I now proceed with exporting it?

I don't know if this has something to do with it, but this project uses multiple targets, however I am just trying to **Archive** one of those targets.

I checked the build logs and this is what I got:

[image]

I do an `ls` once again, nothing there:

```
➜  NFIBEngage 9-5-19, 2.43 PM.xcarchive ls
➜  NFIBEngage 9-5-19, 2.43 PM.xcarchive
```

Comment: Does an archive exist on the file system? Usually in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<date>/ProjectName <date>.xcarchive`. If it's there but not in Organizer, it's possible that Spotlight is not indexing that location.

Comment: @Rudedog, so the archive is there and not in the Organizer, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on your screenshot, it looks like you're trying to archive a static library.

This doesn't make a lot sense in the context of archiving, which is used to bundle all the pieces needed to publish an app, either through the app store or with some other distribution mechanism. A static library is just a single file, so you don't need to archive it. After building it, you can just find the `.a` file by looking for it in the Products folder in the Xcode project, right-clicking on the library and selecting "Show in Finder".

However, if you really want to create an archive of just that library, go to the library's build settings, and ensure that "Skip Install" is No. This setting says whether or not this target should be included as a product when doing an archive.

Keep in mind that if you have this set to No and your app links with this library, then it will be included in the app's archive as well. This means that app won't be distributable, because its archive contains more than one product (the `.app` bundle and the `.a` file).

Comment: I am afraid you actually lost me here. I go to **Product** and then **Archive**, if thats not how to archive the application, then how?

Comment: Product->Archive archives the currently-selected target. Based on the log screenshot you posted, the currently-selected target must have been NFIBEngage, which is a static library, so Xcode dutifully tried to archive that target.

Comment: it seems that they are all static libraries, not sure then what is going on. I have selected different targets and the project name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since the archive exists but is not showing up in the Organizer, it suggests that the archive is not indexed by Spotlight.

The first thing to do is check that the disk and the archive location are not excluded from Spotlight. Go to System Preferences -> Spotlight and check on the privacy tab. If the archives folder -- or the disk that contains the archives folder -- is listed there, then Spotlight won't index the archive, and Organizer will never see it.

If there's nothing in the privacy tab, then you could try [rebuilding your Spotlight index](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716).

You can also see what spotlight metadata the archive has with the following command:

```
mdls ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/the/path/to/myapp.xcarchive
```

The important things to look for are that `kMDItemKind` is set to "Xcode Archive" and `kMDItemContentType` is set to `com.apple.xcode.archive`.

Another useful command is

```
mdimport -t -d3 ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/the/path/to/myapp.xcarchive
```

This will tell you what Spotlight *thinks* this archive's metadata should be.

Comment: thanks. I also found when doing an `ls` on `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<date>/ProjectName <date>.xcarchive` that there is nothing there. So Archive runs successfully and archives nothing? total count is 0. There is nothing in that directory, not sure whats going on there, never had such an experience.

Comment: That’s weird. Have you looked at the build log to see what it did?

Comment: I pasted above what the build log has to say. It just compiled everything mentioned unused variables and parameters, created a static library, not sure what I can glean from this.